# Onchange in Google script to change table data

Tags: google-apps-script

Here's what I'm trying to do I want to get the value of the select to var lob so that if I selected a value it will change the data on the table:

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
<? var list = SpreadsheetApp
.openById('sheetID')
.getSheetByName("VL Slots")
.getDataRange()
.getValues();
var lane = [1];
?>
<? for (var l = 3; l < list.length; l++) { ?>
<option value="<?= list[l][lane] ?>"><?= list[l][lane] ?> </option>
<?}?>
</select>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var lob = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
}
</script>
<? var lob; ?>
<table>
<? var data = SpreadsheetApp
.openById('sheetID')
.getSheetByName("VL Request")
.getDataRange()
.getValues();
var rid = [0];
var request = [1];
<? for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
<tr>
<? if (data[i][rid] === lob) { ?>
<td>data[i][request] </td>
<? } ?>
</tr>
<? } ?>
</table>
```

I hope someone help me on how to do it right.

Answer (score 1):

- You are using scriptlets. As per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates):

> Because scriptlet code executes before the page is served, it can
>   only run once per page;

This means that if your spreadsheet data changes, your html table will not incorporate the change.

- The Apps Script [onChange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onChange()) trigger can run an Apps Script code, fired by a change in the document. However, I assume that you are deploying a Web App, and the WebApp will not be updated by an onChange trigger, unless you refresh your browser manually.
- For your situation you best bet would be to use [polling](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) for refreshing the data in your website in combination with [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

**Sample:**

> code.gs

```
function doGet()
{
  var html=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  return html.evaluate();
}

function getSelect() {
  var list = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadssheetID').getSheetByName("VL Slots").getDataRange().getValues();
  var lane = 1;
  var select="";
  for (var l = 3; l < list.length; l++) {
    select+='<option value="' + list[l][lane] + '">'+ list[l][lane] + ' </option>';
  }
  return select;
}
function getTable(lob) {
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadssheetID').getSheetByName("VL Request").getDataRange().getValues();
  var rid = 0;
  var request = 1;
  var table="";
  table+='<tr>';
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) { 
    if (data[i][rid] == lob) {
      table+='<td>' + data[i][request] + '</td>';
    }
  }
  table+='</tr>';
  return  table;
}
```

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <script>
  function populateSelect(){
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getSelect();
   }
  function onSuccess(select){
    document.getElementById("mySelect").innerHTML=select;
  }
  function polling(){
    setInterval(myFunction,2000);
   }
  function myFunction(){
    var lob = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess2).getTable(lob);    

  }
  function onSuccess2(table){
    document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML=table;
  }
  </script>
  <body onload="populateSelect()">
    <select id="mySelect" onchange="polling()">
    </select>
    <table id="myTable">
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

> `setInterval(myFunction,2000);` will refresh your data in desired
>   intervals (in ms).

Comment: it is working great. However, it affects my other script. Because I have a script that can click the row to gather the data on the specific row to input in a form.  Is there anything I need to do to make it work?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your other script.

Comment: I added the script as an answer. That's what Im trying to acheive.