# Script Conflict Onchange and table row selection

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

So the script is to allow me to click the row in the table and set the input value in the form whatever the data of the selected row. However, this script is not working when I incorporate the solution for the onchange. I was thinking if there's conflict on the scripts? This is just a follow-up on this query: 
[Onchange in Google script to change table data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58401070/onchange-in-google-script-to-change-table-data/58410721?noredirect=1)

Here's the current code I am trying to figure out.

> code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  var html=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  return html.evaluate();
}

function getSelect() {
  var list = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadssheetID').getSheetByName("VL Slots").getDataRange().getValues();
  var lane = 1;
  var select="";
  for (var l = 3; l < list.length; l++) {
    select+='<option value="' + list[l][lane] + '">'+ list[l][lane] + ' </option>';
  }
  return select;
}

function getTable(lob) {
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadssheetID').getSheetByName("VL Request").getDataRange().getValues();
  var rid = 0;
  var request = 1;
  var table="";
  table+='<tr>';
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) { 
    if (data[i][rid] == lob) {
      table+='<td>' + data[i][request] + '</td>';
    }
  }
  table+='</tr>';
  return  table;
}
```

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <script>
    function populateSelect() {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getSelect();
    }
    function onSuccess(select) {
      document.getElementById("mySelect").innerHTML=select;
    }
    function polling() {
      setInterval(myFunction, 2000);
    }
    function myFunction() {
      var lob = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess2).getTable(lob);    
    }
    function onSuccess2(table) {
      document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML=table;
    }
  </script>
  <body onload="populateSelect()">
    <select id="mySelect" onchange="polling()"></select>
    <table id="myTable"> </table>
    <form id="logForm">
      <label>Request <span class="required">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" id="request" name="request" class="field-long" placeholder="Request" readonly /> 
    </form>

    <script>    
      var table = document.getElementById('myTable');    
      for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        table.rows[i].onclick = function() {
          //rIndex = this.rowIndex;
          document.getElementById("request").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML.trim();    
        };
      }    
    </script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, can you share a sanitized copy of the spreadsheet you are working on? Also, is the script showing any errors? Or just not doing what you expect?

Comment: Actually, it's working on the first load. However,when I select on the dropdown that's the time I won't be able to gather the data when I click on a row.

Comment: I hope someone might help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I've reworked your code a bit so that it sets the input value when you click a value in the table. To do that, I have created a new function in the html script, and deleted the script you wrote below the body elements.

First, when creating the table, each table element gets an onclick event that calls the function writeThis, which accepts one parameter (in this case, the text to be set in the input):

```
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) { 
    if (data[i][rid] == lob) {
      var inputData = data[i][request]
      table += '<td onclick=writeThis(this.id) id="' + inputData + '">' + inputData + '</td>';
    }
  }
```

And the function called, `writeThis(input)`, fires on click and sets the new input:

```
    function writeThis(input) {
      document.getElementById("request").value = input;
    }
```

I've also improved indentation a bit in the rest of the code. This is the full code:

> Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  var html=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  return html.evaluate();
}

// Create a dropdown option for each row in VL Slots
function getSelect() {
  var list = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadssheetID').getSheetByName("VL Slots").getDataRange().getValues();
  var lane = 1;
  var select="";
  for (var l = 3; l < list.length; l++) {
    select+='<option value="' + list[l][lane] + '">'+ list[l][lane] + ' </option>';
  }
  return select;
}

// Create a table with all the data from VL Request where parameter matches data
function getTable(lob) {
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadssheetID').getSheetByName("VL Request").getDataRange().getValues();
  var rid = 0;
  var request = 1;
  var table = '<tr>';
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) { 
    if (data[i][rid] == lob) {
      var inputData = data[i][request]
      table += '<td onclick=writeThis(this.id) id="' + inputData + '">' + inputData + '</td>';
    }
  }
  table+='</tr>';
  return  table;
}
```

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <script>
    function populateSelect() {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getSelect();
    }
    function onSuccess(select) {
      document.getElementById("mySelect").innerHTML=select;
    }
    function polling() {
      setInterval(myFunction, 2000);
    }
    function myFunction() {
      var lob = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess2).getTable(lob);    
    }
    function onSuccess2(table) {
      document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML=table;
    }
    function writeThis(input) {
      document.getElementById("request").value = input;
    }
  </script>
  <body onload="populateSelect()">
    <select id="mySelect" onchange="polling()"></select>
    <table id="myTable"> </table>
    <form id="logForm">
      <label>Request 
        <span class="required">*</span>
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="request" name="request" class="field-long" placeholder="Request" readonly /> 
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I've tried it but it didn't work. :) If in case I would also like to do this with more than one td and input.  So for each data on td it will have a designated input.

Comment: That's really strange, because I just tried it and it is working for me. Did you change the spreadsheet id to yours? How is it failing? Table not appearing? Input not changing on click? Also, it would be useful to have a sanitized sample of the spreadsheet you are working on.